# Is there any way to export (static link) an SFML project made in Dev C++?

Tags: c++, export, sfml

I've seen that there are only tutorials of static linking SFML projects for Code Blocks and Visual Studio, but there isn't one for Dev C++. What I basically want is the executable to be independent, without having to execute it in the IDE. Anyone has any idea? Is it possible? I'm currently using Dev C++ 5.11 with the MinGW 64 bit compiler and the 2.4.2 version of SFML.

Comment: The concept is the same no matter which IDE you're using. You should be able to adapt the Code Blocks instructions.

Comment: I know the process should be the same in every IDE. But I'm a bit of an amateur and I don't really know how to "adapt" the instructions of the Code Blocks tutorial to Dev C++. I tried and these two (Code Blocks and Dev C++) are definitely not so similar.

Answer (score 0):

Dev-C++ as well as most other IDE (Code::Blocks, Qt Creator, etc.) just provide a GUI to configure flags which will then be passed on to an underlying compiler.

As such you can more or less follow the Code::Blocks tutorial and just map the different GUI fields to the ones available in Dev-C++.

Essentially, make sure to use the libraries with the `-s` suffix and to define `SFML_STATIC`.

Here's an example image I found, as I don't necessarily want to install Dev-C++:

[image: Dev-C++ library linking]

On the right side under "Linker" you can add the SFML static libraries (e.g. -lsfml-graphics-s) and under "Preprocessor Definitions" at the bottom you can add `SFML_STATIC`

Comment: I don't really know how to do it. But thanks for the information though.

Comment: I added some more information on how the UI would work, hope it helps.